# Windows application to pull through xml data based on xpath with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, xpath, visual-studio-2015, windows

I'm trying to create a program that reads the xml data and pulls through the data based on the xpath input. I have a couple of questions i need help with:

1) It is only pulling through the first node where I want it to pull through all nodes. My code is below, can you advise what I need to amend to do this so rather than just pulling through the first answer it pulls through all the data relevant to that path?

2) I have added a third textbox (which is not coded in yet) that you can input a condition so it works with the first xpath value The example is below:

/Clients/Client1/Name (This is the value)

Clients/Client1[Name = 'Smith'] (this is the condition)

I dont know how to code this part to work wih the first text box that is looking at the value?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lPrompt.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.Load(tbFile.Text);
                XPathNavigator xnav = xdoc.CreateNavigator();

                bool innerXml = checkBox2.Checked;

                if (innerXml)
                textBox2.Text = xnav.SelectSingleNode(textBox1.Text).InnerXml.ToString();
                else
                textBox2.Text = xnav.SelectSingleNode(textBox1.Text).Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                textBox2.Text = ex.Message;
                textBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
```

[Xpath Program Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J94Cj.jpg)

I know there is multiple programs I can use like Xpath Visualizer etc but I need this to be very specific to what I'm working on so I need to have a separate box where I can add conditions.

Comment: I don't understand too much, but see if you have an alternative for `SelectSingleNode` to find all the nodes if this is what you need.

Comment: Hi Lauda, I tried that but it does not have that as an option for SelectNode on xnav